# Error Providers

Tags: c#, winforms, errorprovider

I am trying to apply error providers to a text box,

The user cannot enter more than 25 characters
The textbox cannot be left blank

```
private void txtNameandSurn_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtNameandSurn.MaxLength = 25;

    if (txtNameandSurn.Text == "")
    {
        txtNameandSurn.BackColor = Color.White;
        errorProvider1.SetError(txtNameandSurn, "Cannot be blank!");
    }
    else
    {
        txtNameandSurn.BackColor = Color.Red;
        errorProvider1.SetError(txtNameandSurn, "");
    }

    if (txtNameandSurn.Text.Length >= txtNameandSurn.MaxLength)
    {
        errorProvider1.SetError(txtNameandSurn, "Cannot input more than 25 characters!");
    }
    else if (txtNameandSurn.Text.Length < txtNameandSurn.MaxLength)
    {
        errorProvider1.SetError(txtNameandSurn, "");
    }
}
```

The issue I have is with the character input, the error provider shows up but when i press another key the icon for the errorprovider disappears but the character is not inputted which is good. How do I keep the error provider icon showing?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

You should rewrite your conditions in a logical manner. Every case where there is not a correct input should have it's definition and have the correct error set. In the other case (input is correct), remove the error. Simplified it should look like this:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
{
    errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "Cannot be blank!");
}
else if(textBox1.Text.Length >= textBox1.MaxLength)
{
    errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "Cannot input more than 25 characters!");
}
else
{
    errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "");
}
```

This way, you can add more conditions easiliy. If you want for example that the tekst doesn't contain a `#`, simply add following statement:

```
if(textBox1.Contains("#"))
{
    errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "Cannot contain a '#'!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For great readability and flexibility for adding new rules, I prefer this syntax.  Note that this also lends itself to creating reusable sets of rules for specific data types.
This untested code should solve your problem with the errorProvider, if I understood it.

```
    class Rule 
    { 
        public Func<string, bool> Test { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }

    private void txtNameandSurn_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var rules = new List<Rule>()
        {
            new Rule() { Test = s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s), Message="String cannot be blank." },
            new Rule() { Test = s => (s.Length <= txtNameandSurn.MaxLength), Message="String cannot be longer than " + txtNameandSurn.MaxLength },
            new Rule() { Test = s => !s.Contains("#"), Message = "String cannot contain a hash character." }
        };

        var isValid = rules.All(r => r.Test(txtNameandSurn.Text));

        string[] message;
        if (!isValid)
        {
            message = rules.Where(r => r.Test(txtNameandSurn.Text) == false).Select(r => r.Message);
        }

        errorProvider1.SetError((message.Length > 0) ? (string.Join(';', message)) : "");
    }
```

Comment: The error provider doesn't state it should not contain a # character but it should not contain all special characters such as #@!$%^&*() etc..

Comment: Sure... you should easily be able to use RegEx to test for those characters.

Comment: I have never used such a thing this is my first year on windows form sorry

Comment: This will help you, LukeBorg:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b6d281e2-20f4-4009-b217-fd9a054bf2b5/regular-expression-validation-for-textbox-in-windows-forms-application?forum=winforms

Comment: While you're working on that regex issue, if Abbas or I answered your original question, please do the courtesy of marking an answer.  If we have not, let us know where we missed the mark so we can refine our answers.

Comment: +1 for this Kevin as it provides a more mature method for executing a set of rules/validations.  Hey Luke, you should accept an answer.

Comment: There should be a white checkmark beside each answer.  When you click it (beside the response that best answered your question) it'll turn green.  You can only pick one.  If two answers are equivalent, give it to the person who responded first.